# Cutting a string into groups of n

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to take a string,

`msg = 'hello world'`

and after joining each word together so there's no spaces, separate the string into a string or a list of blocks of n:

`msg2 = 'hellowo orld' # n is 7.`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Comment: I tried what another user suggested: 

```n = 7
msg = 'hello world'
msg = msg.replace(' ', '')
' '.join(msg[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(msg), n))``` But it didn't work

Comment: There's an `itertools` recipe for a function named [`grouper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that can do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
n = 7
msg = 'hello world'
msg = msg.replace(' ', '')
' '.join(msg[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(msg), n))
```

Basically, you are removing the spaces with `msg.replace(' ', '')`, then you are splitting the string at every nth characters, and joining these items separated by a space.

If you want to put everything in a function:

```py
def sep(msg):
    n = 7
    msg = msg.replace(' ', '')
    return ' '.join(msg[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(msg), n))
```

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf here's what I wrote: 
```def sep (msg):
 n = 7
 msg = msg.replace(' ', '')
 ' '.join(msg[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(msg), n))```
But it causes `TypeError : list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @locrian.elder, ??

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf here's what I wrote: 

```def sep (msg): 
    n = 7 
    msg = msg.replace(' ', '') 
    ' '.join(msg[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(msg), n))```

But it causes `TypeError : list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @locrian.elder I typed that exact code (with newlines added) and it did not give me an error. You may want to return a value from your function though, rather than just evaluate it.

Comment: @locrian.elder, I agree with nog642, the function is not returning an error at all. I also agree you should use a `return` statement at the end of the function.